# Duplicate Street Address: Line 1 Label : Magento 2.3.2

Tags: checkout, magento2.3, shipping-address, labels

I am using Magento  2.3.2

> On checkout page there is double label about "Street Address: Line 1"

Is it a bug on my Magento ?

I can not translate as well

How can I remove it?

Any idea?

> Screen
>
> https://ibb.co/N157KcX

Comment: Same issue here, did you ever find a solution? Happened to me after upgrading from 2.3.0 to 2.3.3

Comment: Do you maybe also use the porto theme?

Comment: it is appear when the Fastest theme active

Comment: in blank and Luma theme it is okay

Comment: @SandervanZuidam I think you have a solution to hide with css, would you please explain how ?

Answer (score 3):

No the proper solution that works is, otherwise it will hide the whole first address line and the next button will not work anymore

[name*="shippingAddress.street.0"] .label {display: none;}

Answer (score 2):

I used to

```
[name*="shippingAddress.street.0"] .label {display: none;}
```

in css

it is not proper solution but the label disapper

Comment: Please do not use this solution, it caused me hours of troubleshooting with a broken checkout. Forgot I added hit :-)This above code hides the street 1 address line instead of the label.

Comment: Thats way I used syntax

Answer (score 2):

The syntax is bad.
The good solution:

```
[name*="shippingAddress.street.0"] {display: none;}
```